# how do you throw an error from RXJS Observable retryWhen

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I need to retry a sequence of RxJS observables and throw the error object of the item in the sequence if the collection is not successful after 3 attempts.  I found this example ([An incremental back-off strategy for handling errors](https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/getting_started_with_rxjs/creating_and_querying_observable_sequences/error_handling.html)):

```
var source = get('url').retryWhen(
attempts =>
attempts
  .zip(Observable.range(1, 3), (_, i) => i)
  .flatMap(i => {
    console.log('delay retry by ' + i + ' second(s)');
    return Rx.Observable.timer(i * 1000);
  });
);

var subscription = source.subscribe(
data => {
// Displays the data from the URL or cached data
console.log(data);
});
```

How do you throw the error belonging to the item in the collection?  The above code seems to swallow the error as opposed to surfacing it to the caller to handle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your stream you basically just stripped away the error and solely considered the *count* by using this selector-function in your `zip`: `(_, i) => i` - where `_` would be the error.

I've adjusted your stream and removed the selector-function, which is not really needed here - now it will retry 3 times and then throw the error if it fails again.

```js
const source = Rx.Observable.create(o => {
    o.error(new Error("always fails"));
  })
  .retryWhen(attempts => attempts
    .zip(Rx.Observable.range(1, 4))
    .flatMap(([error, i]) => {
      if (i > 3) {
        return Rx.Observable.throw(error);
      }
      console.log('delay retry by ' + i + ' second(s)');
      return Rx.Observable.timer(i * 100);
    })
  );

source.subscribe(
  data => console.log(data),
  error => console.error(error)
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```